# How to get the Docker version using the Remote API

Tags: docker

Is it possible to get the Docker service version using the Remote API, that is, something similar to passing the version parameter to the command line client?

```
docker --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it's [the `/version` endpoint](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.20/#show-the-docker-version-information).

From the docs:

> Example request:
>
> ```
> GET /version HTTP/1.1
> ```
>
> Example response:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> {
>      "Version": "1.5.0",
>      "Os": "linux",
>      "KernelVersion": "3.18.5-tinycore64",
>      "GoVersion": "go1.4.1",
>      "GitCommit": "a8a31ef",
>      "Arch": "amd64",
>      "ApiVersion": "1.20",
>      "Experimental": false
> }
> ```